# How can I get Castle Windsor to automatically inject a property?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, property-injection

I have a property on my classes for logging service.

```
private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
public ILogger Logger
{
    get { return logger; }
    set { logger = value; }
}
```

And I have this in my component registration:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(x => new LoggingFacility(LoggerImplementation.Log4net));
```

However, Windsor doesn't seem to inject the Logger - am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lambda parameter for AddFacility is actually a creation callback (it gets called when the facility is created), not a factory.

Use this instead:

```
container.AddFacility("logging", new LoggingFacility(LoggerImplementation.Log4net, "path_to_log4net.config"));
```

BTW Windsor automatically injects property dependencies whenever it can.

Comment: Thank you, you are starting to become my personal Windsor assistant :-)